# Django send mail back to the user who sends in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-email

I have a contactform on my site.

When submitted a mail is sent to me. But I also want to send the user a mail, letting the user know that I have received the form submission.

When I try to put the `email` value as a recipient, I get this error: `AssertionError: "to" argument must be a list or tuple`

Anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```
def show_contactform(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            f = ContactForm(request.POST)
            f.save()

            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            subject = "New contact from website"
            recipients = ['contact@company.com']
            rendered = render_to_string('forms/email_body.html', {'form':form)


            to_user_subject = "Contact registred"
            to_user_rendered = render_to_string('form/to_user_email_contact.html', {'form_headline':subject})



            #Send content to celery worker for asynchronous mail outbox - sending to company
            tasks.send_email.delay(subject=subject, rendered=rendered, email=email, recipients=recipients)

            #Send content to celery worker for asynchronous mail outbox - sending to the user who sent the form
            tasks.send_email.delay(subject=to_user_subject, rendered=to_user_rendered, email=recipients, recipients=email)


            return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/contact/success/')

    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact/form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

---

```
@task()
def send_email(subject, rendered, email, recipients):

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, rendered, email, recipients)
    msg.attach_alternative(rendered, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Comment: in your second task add [] around email e.g. recipients=[email], it works in the first takes because the recipients var is a list, email=recipients would also need to a single item not a list

Comment: Great! But now I get the error: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` on the "from" address.

Comment: Changed `email=recipients` to email='contact@company.com', and now it work.